# Cokernel: Inspiration for it's name?

Tags: terminology, definition, math-history

The cokernel, as currently defined, is the set of "linear constraints". (Wording due to Jonathan Zhu.)

What is the reason for the name cokernel?

Intuitively, a cokernel should complement a kernel. This does not seem to be the case.
Indeed, intuitively, you would think the cokernel corresponds to the image of an operator, as the dimension formula and other considerations would suggest. Similarly the co-image should be the kernel.

Is there a more compelling reason for the nomenclature?

Aside:"Its" really should be "it's”. Apostrophes to possessives. Let "its" be it's own word denoting "it is”.

Of course, I'm well-familiar with definitions from linear algebra. I do not know category theory.

Perhaps, a mismatch of attributes.

Edit: I'm not sure why my comments are being deleted. Some of them are included below.

I do not lack mathematical maturity. I am a Harvard Mathematics PhD student on medical leave. I believe to abstract too much is to be stuck in the midgame some days. When does abstraction become obfuscation?

Comment: Sadly to understand the choice of these names one must have a little mathematical maturity. Indeed it is often useful to use "universal properties" to define objects. The "co" part comes in when we reverse the direction all the arrows in the universal property. It turns out this is a particularly compelling reason, however as an undergraduate I concur that I was often annoyed by such seemingly unintuitive naming.

Comment: There is an entire section in [the wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cokernel) devoted to intuition, and it seems to me ample explanation of why the terminology is used.

Comment: @Benji I am sorry if I offended you of course the "Assume" joke is clearly relevant here. I do however believe the point stands that this is a compelling reason, of course it is easier to define things in the usual way, but it is powerful to view them from the abstract perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Mummy already gave out the idea but let me add some details (which required  to put this as an answer and not a comment). Instead of thinking of "co" as related to "complement", we should in fact think of it as related to "quotient", at least in the following cases: let $W \subset V$ be a subvector space, or a subgroup or an ideal. One has the following short exact sequence
$$ {0} \longrightarrow W \overset{\iota}{\longrightarrow} V \overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow} V/ W \longrightarrow {0}$$
(image of a map has to be equal to the kernel of the next map, example at "V", $\operatorname{Im}\iota = \operatorname{Ker}\pi$. The condition at "W" and $V/W$ give injectivity of $\iota$ and surjectivity of $\pi$).

Hmm..., in fact I'm not sure at all about the following as I did not use categories for a while now... In some categories, these short exact sequences split (or maybe if they split on the left, then they also split on the right etc.). To make it short, I' trying to say that we have $V = W \oplus V/W$ and any complementary to $W$ will in fact be isomorphic to $V/W$ which is why in the first years, it seems unnecessary to introduce quotient, at least in this example. (That splitting on the left and splitting on the right is the abstract way to say that in this case, complementaries and quotient can be identified)

Reversing arrows give formally similar universal properties but their interpretation are in fact often very different.

Another remark: a map is injective if its kernel is reduced to 0 (neutral element), it is surjective if its cokernel is 0.

Remark to the aside: the "s" does not come from the verb to be, it comes from declination, it is the form of the genetif, cf. german.

Comment: Ah, I think something got back to my mind: if a short exact sequence splits on the right, then the object in the middle of the exact sequence is a coproduct (of the two in the sides, here $V$ coproduct of $W$ and $V/W$). If the sequence splits on the left, then the object in the middle is a product of the two others. In some categories (name? certainly abelian, but sthg more specific), finite products and coproducts coincide. That's the case for abelian groups and vector spaces.

Comment: Quick remark on the first part: The "co" prefix has little to do with quotients either, though. Rather, it denotes the dual or a certain construction.

Comment: That's exactly what Mummy said (and in fact I would rather say "reverse the arrow" than duality as this also has a meaning. Although I would indeed say duality "subobject/quotient"). As a matter of fact, I wanted to get from the abstract to the particular case of the OP, especially that the word codimension immediatly came to my mind.

Comment: The canonical map from the coproduct to the product is an isomorphism if the category you're in is additive. As for your second paragraph, it's true that in any Abelian category the condition that an SES $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ splits on the left is equivalent to the condition that it splits on the right, which is equivalent to saying that $B\cong A\oplus C.$ However, I don't believe there is standard terminology for categories where every SES is split (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327899/name-for-abelian-category-in-which-every-short-exact-sequence-splits)).